# Xubuntu doesn't allow music to play when I lock screen

Tags: xubuntu, music, lock-screen

If I'm locking my screen with xflock4 while playing some music, the music pauses. However, it resumes as soon as I login again.

How do I play my music while my screen is locked?

Comment: what is your music player?  please add that to your question together with the version of xubuntu you are using.

Comment: The explanation is cited [here][1]. It's not a bug, it's a feature ;)


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/450443/light-locker-stops-background-activities-eg-music-playback-when-screen-is-loc

Comment: @fossfreedom, That shouldn't matter. X defines standard signals for next/prev/play/mute.