# Light locker stops background activities (eg. music playback) when screen is locked

Tags: xubuntu, 14.04, lock-screen, light-locker

I upgraded my xubuntu installation to the new release, 14.04. This release includes a new light-locker, a great improvement if you ask me. The thing is that whenever I try to lock the session or when it locks automatically after some time, it stops (or pause) playback of music, for instance (I have just noticed this while having some music played in the background on youtube).

When I unlock the session it resumes playing instantly. I've looked for some options in the settings, but didn't see any. Also, I found this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-locker/+bug/1296456 which if I understand correctly fixes this situation in version 1.4.0. Sadly, this is the version xubuntu 14.04 ships with, but the problem still exists. What should I do ?

Comment: Thanks for this. After upgrade I could not get XScreenSaver to start on lock-screen, simply needed to disable light-locker in the settings dialog to let XScreenSaver take control.

Comment: In my Xubuntu no solution works - i have added my user to the audio group, audio still stops. I dont have any of the options mentioned here https://xubuntu.org/news/screen-locking-in-xubuntu-14-04/ in the light locker menu. Would anyone have a screenshot or else please? I have 16.04.3.

Answer (score 15):

Here is what [xubuntu.org](http://xubuntu.org/news/screen-locking-in-xubuntu-14-04/) has to say about this:

> [...]
> Currently, when locking, it is assumed you are either:
>
> 1. in a public space of sorts (the desktop at home hardly needs locking) and have walked away from the machine
> 2. using a system with more than one user
>
> Stopping/pausing playback in both of these scenarios make sense.
>
> However, this might be an annoying change for users used to having
> their music playback continue even when their session locks. If you
> don’t like this behavior, there are basically two solutions:
>
> 1. Set light-locker to lock the session “When the screensaver is deactivated”
> 2. Switch back to using xscreensaver
> 3. Add your user to the `audio` group on your computer and  music playback will continue also with light-locker
>
> The first option is a good workaround, because it means that your
> audio-playback will continue when the screen has been blanked.
> However, when you wake up your computer, e.g. by touching the mouse,
> it will pause the music until you log into your session again. The
> third solution is mentioned last, because it is not advised to add a
> user to the `audio` group (read [The Audio Group](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/TheAudioGroup?highlight=%28audio%29) wiki page for a
> comprehensive explanation). However, as long as you are on a
> single-user system, this might still be an option for you. [...]

[image: light-locker]

**Figure 1:** Light-locker, by default, will lock out sound.

For those who choose workaround 2, here is how to remove `light-locker` and install good old `xscreensaver`:

```
sudo apt-get purge light-locker light-locker-settings
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver
```

After installation, a "Screensaver" icon will appear in the "Settings Manager" menu. Clicking it allows to configure `xscreensaver`.

[image: xscreensaver]

**Figure 2:** XScreenSaver

Comment: My opinion about this: A locker serves to prevent unattended computer **input**, not to switch off useful computer **output**. Xubuntu developers should not make presumptions about the whereabouts and use of any computer. They should solve this annoying regression by adding a "Computer in public space" toggle switch defaulting to historic Xubuntu behaviour.

Comment: This is still an issue with Xubuntu 16.04! Above solution remains valid.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I went to the Light Locker Settings and in "Automatically lock the session" I changed it to "When the screensaver is deactivated". Music is now still playing when the screen goes blank. Seems though that it now takes longer to return to the lock screen.

**UPDATE**: Seems like I need to do two touches/keystrokes to activate the lock screen. When I click the mouse once, the musics stops, and it needs one keystroke more before the Light Locker appears. Annoying.

Comment: I think that the xscreensaver's behaviour is not possible with light locker, unfortunately. perhaps the team behind light locker will consider and add this feature in a future release.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same issue with Linux Mint using XFCE desktop. What I did is to replace light-locker with cinnamon-screensaver (which is nicer than xscreensaver and gnome-screensaver).

```sh
sudo apt-get remove light-locker
sudo apt-get install cinnamon-screensaver
```

Then edit the `for-loop` in the file `/usr/bin/xflock4` to add the command that triggers cinnamon-screensaver like below:

```sh
for lock_cmd in \
    "cinnamon-screensaver-command -l" \        # this is the added line
    ....
```